# GitHub Packages, Install Android library, Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, github

I successfully uploaded my package to GitHub

[image]

In my project when i upload i use

```
    def getVersionName = { ->
    return "1.0.0" // Replace with version Name
}

def getArtifactId = { ->
    return "bruno-components" // Replace with library name ID
}

publishing {
    publications {
        bar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.bruno.components' // Replace with group ID
            artifactId getArtifactId()
            version getVersionName()
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${getArtifactId()}-debug.aar")
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"
            /** Configure path of your package repository on Github
             ** Replace GITHUB_USERID with your/organisation Github userID
             ** and REPOSITORY with the repository name on GitHub
             */
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/bruno/bruno-components-android")
            credentials {
                /** Create github.properties in root project folder file with
                 ** gpr.usr=GITHUB_USER_ID & gpr.key=PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN
                 ** Set env variable GPR_USER & GPR_API_KEY if not adding a properties file**/
                username = githubProperties['gpr.usr']
                password = githubProperties['gpr.key']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I try to use the dependency in another project I get the error:

Failed to resolve: bruno.bruno-components-android:1.0.0:

I use

```
    dependencies {
    
        implementation 'bruno.bruno-components-android:1.0.0'
        implementation 'bruno:bruno-components-android:1.0.0'
    }
    
    repositories {
            maven {
                name = "GitHubPackages"
    
                url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/bruno/bruno-components-android")
                credentials {
                    username = githubProperties['gpr.usr']
                    password = githubProperties['gpr.key']
                }
            }
        }

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'maven-publish'
}
```

to be able to use the dependency I have a token with the read-packages permission

[image]

> Could not find bruno.bruno-components-android:1.0.0:.
> Required by:
> project :app

[image]

Comment: If that screenshot is from after you built the project, it's suspicious that it's never used. You might double-chcek that `gpr.key` in this project is correct.

Comment: It seems strange to me, I also updated the question with what came out of the --debug